# Расширение Jest для VsCode автоматически открывает Test Output в терминале

Tags: visual-studio-code, config, jest

Расширение Jest для VsCode автоматически открывает Test Output в терминале, такое поведение мне очень сильно не нравится.

В [оф](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest) документации говорят выставить флаг `false` для параметра `jest.showTerminalOnLaunch`, но сам VsCode говорит что такой настройки нету.

Подскажите как парвильно настроить VsCode для данного кейса. Спасибо

[image: settings VsCode for jest]

Answer (score 0):

Нашел [ответ](https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/issues/854#issuecomment-1114369018)

Создатель расширения выкатил pre-release 4.5.0, в нем встроена эта фича

Для исправления это проблемы необходимо в vscode выбрать pre-release

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]